# How to use the functions of convertTo, applyColorMap, imshow to replicate matlab output?

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

Here is the code in Matlab and the result picture I get using Matlab. For some purposes, I need to convert Matlab code into C++. I have done the conversion of data structure in C++, and then I need to deal with the part of showing the picture. I decided to use OpenCV library to replace the image processing in Matlab. I have found that some functions like `convertTo`, `applyColorMap` and `imshow` in OpenCV can replace the function `imagesc` in Matlab. So, I imitate the code online I searched. But it doesn't work.

Here is my code in C++:

```
for (cutNumber = 1; cutNumber <= 9; cutNumber++)
{
    momentString = "dBT";
    DataSelect* BaseData_Select = select(theObj,cutNumber,momentString);
    int ncols = BaseData_Select->allLength / BaseData_Select->dataLength;
    // 对应matlab auto.m第138行。下面是绘制dBZ的B显图
    Mat mydata(BaseData_Select->dataLength, ncols, CV_32F);
    for (int i = 0; i < BaseData_Select->dataLength; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < ncols; j++)
        {
            int temmmp = i*ncols+ j;
            mydata.at<float>(i, j) = BaseData_Select->data[i*ncols + j];
        }
    }
    double Amin = *min_element(mydata.begin<float>(), mydata.end<float>()); // Amin is -19
    double Amax = *max_element(mydata.begin<float>(), mydata.end<float>()); // Amax is 64
    cv::minMaxIdx(mydata, &Amin, &Amax);
    cv::Mat adjMap;
    float scale = 255 / (Amax - Amin);
    mydata.convertTo(adjMap, CV_8UC1, scale, -Amin*scale);
    cv::Mat resultMap;
    applyColorMap(adjMap, resultMap, cv::COLORMAP_AUTUMN);
    cv::imshow("Out", resultMap);
    cv::imwrite("output.bmp", resultMap);
}
```

Here is the code dealing with images in Matlab.

```
figure(H_figure_PHIDP);
subplot(3,3,Cut_Number);
imagesc(PHIDP.Data);
colormap('default');
caxis([ -20 60]);
ylim([Sphere_Distance_Cell-Sphere_Distance_Cell_Extend Sphere_Distance_Cell+Sphere_Distance_Cell_Extend])
xlim([Sphere_Center_Ray-Sphere_Azimuth_Cell_Extend Sphere_Center_Ray+Sphere_Azimuth_Cell_Extend])
xlabel('径向数目');
ylabel('距离库');
```

The result picture running on Matlab which is I want to get using OpenCV functions.

[image]

And my result picture in C++ is the following picture which is the wrong picture absolutely.

[image]

Could any one help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Your question is rather unspecific. Please learn to create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and ask *specific* questions about *specific* problems.

Answer (score 0):

imagesc creates an image that is heat map of data. So low values are blueish and high values are reddish. You can use pretty much any scheme.

Steal some colour schemes from here.

http://www.malcolmmclean.site11.com/www/datadensity/DataDensity.html

```
   void createjet(unsigned char *rgb, int N)

   /*
       Convert data matrix to heat map using jet colourscheme
    */
   unsigned char *dataasrgbajet(Mat& mydata, double amin, double amax int *width, int *height)
   {
       int i, j, index;
       unsigned char jet[256*3];
       unsigned char *rgba = malloc(mat.width * mat.height * 4);
       createjet(jet, 256);
       for(i=0;i<mat.height;i++)
         for(j=0;j<mat.width;j++)
         {
            index = ((mat[i][j] - amin) * 256)/(amax - amin);
            index = clamp(index, 0, 255);
            rgba[i*width+j] = jet[index*3];
            rgba[i*width+j+1] = jet[index*3+1];
            rgba[i*width+j+2] = jet[index*3+2]; 
            rgba[i*width+j+3] = 255;
         }
    *width = mat.width;
    *height = mat.height;
    return rgba;
  }
```

There are lots of other colour schemes than jet.

Once you've got data in a clean unsigned char array format, you can very simply integrate it with any third party library you choose for image display purposes.